# JSDoc para React

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, jsdoc

Hola como puedo hacer que al invocar mi componente liste los parametros posibles?

me refiero a vero de este modo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi componete salen otras cosas al documentarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi componente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en caso de quitar los comentarios si los lista pero no dan los posibles valores [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor reduce las imágenes, me parece que con 2 imágenes de ejemplo se puede especificar lo que quieres hacer y el código de ejemplo pásalo como texto, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede hacer hacerlo de 2 maneras, en ambas formas te mostrara los atributos con los que definas que necesita tu componente.

## Utilizando JSDoc

De esta forma es fácil y nos ayuda a documentar también nuestros métodos, al igual que ayuda a proporcionar ayuda con los atributos por el tipado, para mas detalles puedes revisar la [documentación](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html).

```
/**
 * Ejemplo de tipado
 * @param {Object} param0 
 * @param {string} param0.name 
 * @param {number} param0.number
 * @returns 
 */
const TestPropsType = ({ name, number }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hola {name} {number}
        </div>
    )
}
```

### Definir grupo de valores esperados

Esto se puede hacer de 2 maneras o incluso puede que de mas formas distintas que no conozca.
De las 2 formas debería funcionar para definir los valores que se esperan en un parametro(en este caso `props`).

**opción simple**

```
/**
 * Ejemplo de tipado
 * @param {Object} param0 
 * @param {('value1' | 'value2')} param0.name 
 * @param {number} param0.number
 * @returns 
 */
const TestPropsType = ({ name, number }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hola {name} {number}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**usando `typedef`**

```
/**
 * @typedef {"keyvalue" | "bar" | "timeseries" | "pie" | "table"} MetricFormat
 */

/**
 * Ejemplo de tipado
 * @param {Object} param0 
 * @param {('value1' | 'value2')} param0.name 
 * @param {number} param0.number
 * @param {MetricFormat} param0.format
 * @returns 
 */
const TestPropsType = ({ name, number, format }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hola {name} {number}
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

### 2. Utilizando PropTypes

Una ves que definimos el componente y lo que recíbira por `props`, podemos usar [`PropTypes`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) importado de `prop-types` y esto nos ayudara a la hora de ejecutar nuestro código y tener un componente requerido.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TestPropsType = ({ name, number }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hola {name} {number}
        </div>
    )
}

TestPropsType.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    number: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

[Aquí](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) puedes ver un poco mas sobre los tipos, datos requeridos y todo lo que puedes usar con `PropTypes`.

Comment: Eso si me funciona, lo que quiero es que al invocar `@param {string} param0.name` me liste los posibles nombres, es decir `juan || peres || jhon` para el campo name, como en la primera imagen

Comment: @user75463 he actualizado mi respuesta, esto debería servirte para lo que mencionas. 
No olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta.